# Make [idioms] and [phrases] synonyms with their respective [-request] tags?

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

[This recent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/374510/is-there-an-idiom-phrase-which-contains-the-word-head-to-mean-thinking-hard-t) had too many tags, probably because there were pairs of tags ([phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrases)/[phrase-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-requests) and [idioms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idioms)/[idiom-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiom-requests)) that were synonyms of each other, and the poster didn't know which one to use.

Could we make these pairs of tags into synonyms, so that there's less tag proliferation? That is, make [phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrases) and [phrase-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-requests) synonyms, and [idioms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idioms) and [idiom-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiom-requests)?

Comment: Not sure who voted to close this question. It's on-topic and it's clear. If you disagree with it, that's cool, but downvote, don't closevote. Downvoting means "I disagree", closevoting means "This question is off-topic or unclear".

Answer (score 5):

My view: **absolutely not.**

The [phrases](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrases) tag is not the same as [phrase-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-requests) — the first is for questions about phrases, the second for requesting phrases. Similarly for [idioms](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idioms) and [idiom-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/idiom-requests): they are related as they are both about idioms, but a **request for** an idiom is not the same as a **question about** one.

Prompted by this question, I've edited a couple of the tag info pages to make that distinction clearer.

If a question is wrongly tagged, the solution is to edit it [or suggest an edit, if you have less than the 2000 rep required for a direct edit].

Comment: You've misidentified the synonyms in the first paragraph.  As for separating [tag:phrases] and [tag:phrase-requests], in actual practice they get mixed up, as the example illustrates.

Comment: If tags are used wrongly the solution is to edit the question, not to create synonyms where tags cannot be synonymised. In my first paragraph, *phrase* and *idiom* are generic identifiers, not tag names (they get a special boxed format).

Comment: "not all phrases are idioms" seems to imply you think I want one synonymized to the other.

Comment: Synonyms work both ways. Are you suggesting that there should be two pairs of synonyms, or one set of four? Anyway, [phrases] are not the same as [phrase-requests], and similarly for *idioms*.

Comment: Two pairs, one for each  of the two stem words _phrases_ and _idioms_.  I don't think it's practical to separate _x_ and _x-requests_ so you shouldn't try.

Comment: In that case, your question is unclear. "Could we link **one set of synonyms to the other**" doesn't state what you want to suggest, I think.

Comment: However, prompted by this question, I have edited the tag info to help distinguish between [phrase]/[idioms] and their respective [-request] tags.

Comment: That should have been clear from the way I grouped them in the post. Further argument is pointless. Bye.